# NotificationCenter is not working first time when it is posted from viewcontroller to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter

I have 2 ViewControllers called ViewController1 and ViewController2.

I am posting notification from ViewController1 to ViewController2, but at first time when it is posting, at first time NotificationCenter is not working.

When I came back from ViewController2 to ViewController1 and then again if try to move ViewController2 then that time NotificationCenter it is working,

//  ViewController1.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

//Move to next VC
@IBAction func nextButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("callMethodPrint1FromVC2"), object: nil)

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2Id") as? ViewController2
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2!, animated: true)

  } 
}
```

//  ViewController2.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //Recieve notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.print1Method(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("callMethodPrint1FromVC2"), object: nil)
}

@objc func print1Method(notification: Notification) {

    print("Notification came from VC 1")
}

@IBAction func backToVC1(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1Id") as? ViewController1
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2!, animated: true)
}

 //Remove notification object
deinit {

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("callMethodPrint1FromVC2"), object: nil)
}

}
```

**Actual Output**:

When I move ViewController1 to ViewController2 at first time and every time, print1Method method from ViewController2 has to call.

But it is not working as expeted. 
Is there Anu issues in my code or I am missing something?

Comment: are you trying to call print1Method when next button is pressed?

Comment: ha, yes. I am trying to print print1Method method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are posting notification before your view controller is initialized.

there is no need to post notification for calling the method of vc2. instead, directly call the method.

In VC1

```
@IBAction func nextButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

     let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let vc2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ViewController2Id") as ViewController2
     vc2.print1Method()
     navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2!, animated: true)

  } 
}
```

In VC2

```
func print1Method() {

     print("Method called from VC 1")
 }
```

also for the back button, you are doing it wrong. simply pop the view controller from the stack

```
 @IBAction func backToVC1(_ sender: Any) {

     self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It wont call because ViewController2 is not loaded, and It will call for the second time because you are doing Push instead of Pop while moving backwards which in turns remains the ViewController1 in the memory.

Instead remove notifications and call print1Method from ViewController2 Viewdidload/ViewWillappear/Viewdidappear based on your needs. keep some public variable in ViewController2 and assign the value in prepareforsegue method in ViewController1 if you want to pass some data from ViewController1 to ViewController2

and replace your:

```
@IBAction func backToVC1(_ sender: Any) {

     let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let vc2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1Id") as? ViewController1
     navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2!, animated: true)
}
```

to

```
@IBAction func backToVC1(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding just one step.

What we are doing here is calling the home view controller's method addObserver() to register the observer before navigating, and after that, we are posting the NotificationCenter.default.post. By doing this way the observer gets registered first.

In **First View Controller** add this function in your button click

```
func navigate(){
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "travelApp", bundle: nil)
    let VC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "home") as! homeViewController
    VC.addObserver()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name:Notification.Name("myNotificationName"), object: nil,  userInfo: ["hello": "world"])
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
}
```

In **Second View Controller** do this

```
class homeViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func addObserver(){
    print("addObserverCalled")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("myNotificationName"), object: nil)
}

@objc func onNotification(notification:Notification){
    print("NotificationCenter")
    print(notification.userInfo!)
}

}
```